# iOS framework resource files

Tags: frameworks, static-libraries, nsbundle

I have created a framework with bundle files. Bundle files are under resource folder inside the framework. So my problem was whenever someone need to integrate the framework in their project then they have to drag and drop the bundle file from framework resource folder to project. Is possible to programmatically link the framework resource file and read it inside the project?

Comment: What is the type of the files? Is it images?

Comment: Its bundle file which contains xib,images,plist and json files.

Comment: Are you trying to expose the resources directly to the user, or are you trying  to let them use a class or something that in turn uses that resource?  Please make your question far more specific about what you're trying to do and what exactly is happening that falls short of your expectations.

Comment: Resources are supplied along framework. User has consume that image, xib directly in their project. Issue here is user has link the framework in xcode build phase and also drag and drop the framework bundle files to xcode project.

Comment: You can use dynamic frameworks, which works the way that you described. However be aware that dynamic frameworks are supported only in iOS8+

Answer (score 3):

To include the resource bundle, select the target of your framework, and in the Build Phases > Copy bundle resources, click on the + button and add any resource bundle which you wish to have packaged into your framework.

When you build the framework, the resource will be copied. Make sure that this file exists though or you'll get a build error.

If you go in "Edit Schemes" for your framework project, in the "Build" section, you can add the resource file, so that when you will build the framework, it will also rebuild the resource bundle.